# Component instance creating twice in angular only when page reloading

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a strange issue in angular (v.10). The scenario is as below.

When I load a URL by js or `routeLink` eg: 'this.router.navigate(['/test']); the test component calls the constructor or `ngOnInit` only once.This behavior is normal and there is no issue with that.( This I have verified it by console.log).

But the issue is , when I reload/refresh the URL eg: 'http://localhost:4200/#/test', the test component class will be calling the `constructor/ngOnInit` two times. (console.log printing the content two times).

This issue is with all the routes, and **happens only when the page is reloaded**.

Here are my code details.

### app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### app-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent
},
```

### test-component.ts

```
export class TestComponent {
    
    constructor(){
        //this will print two times only when page reload/refresh
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

I could not find out the root cause of the issue. I will provide more details if needed.

Comment: It would be better if we have full picture of your routing module or even better to share a https://stackblitz.com

Comment: some hints : 
1) check-out what's happening in the network tab of your browser / fiddler
2) Are you using the {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} or RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ?
3) Try to use another local server (eg:http-server)

Answer (score 1):

After so many tries, I found the issue.
I was using HMR(hot module replacement) in my angular project, which causes the components initialising twice on page reload. I have disabled HMR and is now working fine.

Comment: How did you disable HMR? I am facing the same issue, would really appreciate some help.